# std random functions not working - Qt MinGw

Tags: c++, qt, random, stl, mingw

I am using QtCreator 2.4.1, with QtSdk 4.8.1 and MinGw 4.7.2

I am trying to use the (c++11) random library, but so far I have been unsuccesful. Take the following sample code:

```
#include <random>
...
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
int dice_roll = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 1..6
```

The compiler complains:

> error: 'default_random_engine' is not a member of 'std'
>
> error: 'uniform_int_distribution' is not a member of 'std'

I've got the -std=c++0x flag in my .pro file. All other STL functionality seems to work properly, so I'm puzzled!
I'd be grateful if someone could give me a hand with this.

Comment: What is your version of GCC? (it's apparently not the same as the MinGW version as GCC 4.8 haven't been released yet).

Comment: Thanks Joachim for pointing out my mistake. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Check the logs that the `-std=c++0x` flag is properly set (and you should change it to `-std=c++11` btw.). The code [works fine](http://ideone.com/Eu77jb).

Comment: -std=c++11 doesn't work: 'unrecognised command line option'. What logs do you mean? The compile output? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the compile output. Also, if the `-std=c++11` flag doesn't work, it means you have GCC version 4.6 or earlier, and that might not have full C++11 support.

Comment: Bang on! For some reason my tool chain had gone back to MinGW v4.4. Set it to v4.7.2 and problems are gone! How can I give you credit for your help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, silly problem, but might happen to others, so here we go:

For some reason my code was being compiled with MinGW 4.4, the version that shipped by default with my Qt Creator. To bring it back to MinGw 4.7.2, which I already had installed in my computer, I clicked on the 'Projects' tab on the left of the QCreator screen, then selected the correct tool chain.

Thanks loads to Joachim Pileborg for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and was unable to change the compiler.

I replaced std::rand() with qrand()

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qrand