# Qt qrand in loop in Windows generate same numbers

Tags: c++, qt, random

I have qt application using qml. qrand in loop works wrong, in code works right. This problem
appears only at windows(tried in windows 7 and 8 with with MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit). Here is example:

In main.cpp at begin i print:

```
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
qsrand((uint)time.msec());
```

then in loop i use qrand

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int r1 = qrand() % 150;
        int r2 = qrand() % 150;
        qDebug() << r1 << r2 << endl;
    }
}
```

in output there are 2 different numbers repeats about 200 times, then changes:

```
8 58
8 58
8 58
...
120 1
120 1
120 1
...
```

if i use qrand not in loop, it works right. But, if i make function, that generates random numbers with qrand this function works wrong.
In linux on gcc 64 bit compiler the same code works right, it generates different numbers in every line.
In windows 7 and 8 with MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit qrand works wrong. Also, i tried standard srand and rand(), it also works wrong. I checked (uint)time.msec(), it is always different.
But if i put qsrand into loop program generates not perfect, but different numbers:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
        qsrand((uint)time.msec());
        int r1 = qrand() % 150;
        int r2 = qrand() % 150;
        qDebug() << r1 << r2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Output not perfect couse it qrand just generates different numbers more often, but again not always.

**UPDATE:**
i tried c++11 random in windows and it works. I didn't try it in linux yet. But the question about qrand is still alive.

The c++11 random which i used:
[std random functions not working - Qt MinGw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872314/std-random-functions-not-working-qt-mingw/25211787#25211787)

Comment: 1) Which Qt version exactly are you using? 2) Are you using QtCreator by any chance?

Comment: A question like this would really benefit from a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: 1) 5.4, 2) yes, qtcreatorr

Comment: If s/rand do not work, qs/rand cannot work either, so the real question is not a Qt question then, but why s/rand do not work.

Comment: On this windows i compiled another projects with the same compiler and random worked... But, seems like its compiler question, not qt. Will try to find answers on it.

Comment: @Ivan: do you need to bother or you can just use c++11? By the way, I would be quite worried if an iteration takes more than one milisecond. Is that really true? Why is it so slow? I definitely would not use msec for this purpose in such a non-busy iteration. It is far too much time, not fine-tuned enough. A simple iteration like that should not take for msecs.

Comment: @lpapp: Now i use c++11 and its work. Yes, solution with qsrand in cycle is bad. But i just wondering that strange bug. I searched for some errors with rand generating same numbers in loop and didn't find anything. I have solution for myself, its c++11 random, but for others it can be not a solution.

Comment: @Ivan: not sure if others need a "solution" as I cannot reproduce it personally.

Comment: @lpapp: u tried to reproduce it? Then i think will close this question with answer "Use c++11 random".

Comment: @Ivan: perhaps you could check the implementation differences?

Comment: @lpapp, what do u mean? difference between implementation of old c++ random and c++11 random?

Comment: @Ivan: well, the old is a C function, but yes.

Comment: @lpapp ok! Big thanks for your advices. Will research this question when will have time and will try answer here.

Comment: @Ivan: not sure it is worth your time, but if you are bored, why not ... ;-}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is using c++11 random lib: [std random functions not working - Qt MinGw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872314/std-random-functions-not-working-qt-mingw/25211787#25211787)

I have no time for deep investigation of this question, so its the simplest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As random is base on the clock, if you use random in a loop (which is very fast) the clock doesn't change, and your numbers are all the same.

You should add a pause statement to let the clock change.